# Simple matrix calculation in Scala

Tags: scala, matrix

Suppose I've got a matrix of integers `a` and need to create a new matrix `b` so that `b[i, j]` is sum of `a[i, j]` and its neighbors.

I define a matrix as `Array[Array[Int]]` and write a function `foo` to calculate `b` like this:

```
type Matrix = Array[Array[Int]]

def sumOfNeighbors(a: Matrix, x: Int, y: Int): Int = {

  val range = -1 to 1
  val deltas = range.flatMap { dx => range map {dy => (dx, dy)} }
                    .filter  { case (dx, dy) => dx != 0 || dy != 0 }

  val withinBounds: Int => Boolean = x => x >= 0 && x < a.size
  val coords = deltas.map {case (dx, dy) => (x + dx, y + dy)}
                     .filter {case (i, j) => withinBounds(i) && withinBounds(j)}

  coords.map{case (i, j) => a(i)(j)}.sum
}

def foo(a: Matrix): Matrix =
  a.zipWithIndex map {case (row, i) => 
    row.zipWithIndex.map {case (x, j) => x + sumOfNeighbors(a, i, j)} 
  }
```

Does it make sense ? How would you simplify this code ?

Comment: It doesn't do what its spec "so that b[i, j] is sum of a[i, j] and its neighbors." says as it excludes a[i,j] from the sum with the `filter...`.

Comment: I do add `a[i,j]`. See the `foo` function. I agree that it would be more natural to not filter it out in `sumOfNeighbors` though.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Then there's change that would "simplify this code"! Also, I know I'm making excuses :) but the visual similarity of `case (x,j)` to `case (i, j)` was one reason I missed that...

Comment: A more radical change might be to keep the sums of adjacent cells on the current row, and the row "below" and re-use these when you do the row below. You could pass these on in a `foldLeft` accumulator. It also provides a fairly neat way of handling boundaries (as you would initialise these to zeroes before you did the first row)

Comment: Good point. I should re-use the sums of the row "above". I'll try to write it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code does make sense, but there are a couple tools you could add that could make this expandable, depending on your resources.
If you combine Spark with your Scala code (if feasible) you can utilize some of the mean-shift packages available to Spark. Using RDDs you can do a lot of the same functions.
https://spark-packages.org/?q=tags%3Alsh

If this is just small-scale though, none of this is really necessary.

Comment: Using Breeze library might be better since Spark's `ml` and `mllib` use Vector and Matrix implementations based on those of Breeze. Also, it's Scala's go-to lib for linear algebra.